# python Print the maximum valu dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

i need to print the MAX  grad for Objects
exemple:

First school :

Math:
Student Name :Jim, Grade :100

Sport:
Student Name :karen, Grade :88

```
schools = {"First school " : [{ "Name" : "Jim", "Objects":{"Math" : 100, "sport":80}} ,
                             { "Name" : "karen", "Objects":{"Math" : 80, "sport":88}} ,
                             { "Name" : "rot", "Objects":{"Math" :99, "sport":70}} ,
                             { "Name" : "kevin", "Objects":{"Math" : 80, "sport":70}}],

           "Second school " : [{ "Name" : "Amelia", "Objects":{"Math" : 40, "sport":80}} ,
                             { "Name" : " Cait", "Objects":{"Math" : 50, "sport":70}} ,
                             { "Name" : "Dai", "Objects":{"Math" : 70, "sport":30}} ,
                             { "Name" : "dani", "Objects":{"Math" : 78, "sport":68}}]}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that you can do something like this. But next time attach your attempts to the question please.:

```
for k, v in schools.items():
print (k)
max_sport = v[0]
max_math = v[0]
for i in range(1, len(v)):
    if v[i]["Objects"]["Math"] > max_math["Objects"]["Math"]:
        max_math = v[i]
    if v[i]["Objects"]["sport"] > max_sport["Objects"]["sport"]:
        max_sport = v[i]
print("Math: Student Name :{}, Grade :{}".format(max_math["Name"], max_math["Objects"]["Math"]))
print("Sport: Student Name :{}, Grade :{}".format(max_sport["Name"], max_sport["Objects"]["sport"]))
```